# Top 5 elements in an unsorted array

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

An unsorted array is given and we need to find top 5 elements in an efficient way and we cannot sort the list .

My solution :

- Find the max element in the array. O(n)
- Delete this max element after processing/using it.
- Repeat step 1 & 2 , k times ( 5 times in this case ).

Time Complexity : **O(kn)** / **O(n)** , Space Complexity : **O(1)**.

I think we can find the max element in **O(logN)** , So it can be improved to **O(klogN)**. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Can we do better than this ? Using max-heap would be inefficient I guess?

PS - This is not any homework.

Comment: I don't think you can do any better than O(N) when it comes to finding the max element in an unsorted array. What did you have in mind?

Comment: Why don't you track the top 5 (or k) elements as you traverse the array and then delete them when you are done?  That will be O(n) [or O(logN) if you improve your search algorithm as you say].

Comment: Sorry, you _can't_ find the max element in an _unsorted_ array in O(log n) time. You can do it in a sorted array doing e.g. binary search. But in a sorted array, your problem has a trivial O(1) solution, too.

Comment: I was thinking of find max element using divide and conquer

Comment: But I just figured out it won't be logN. thanks for correcting me . It will be O(3n/2) == O(n).

Comment: @PeterGluck How would i do that ? Can it be done in just 1 iteration?

Comment: Yes, see Heisenburg's solution below.  You save the first 5 values and compare them against each subsequent value, dropping the lowest value each time.  This will find your 5 maximum values in one pass.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can use an auxiliary heap (a min heap with minus element at top) you can do that in `O(nlogm)`, where `n` is the list length and `m` the number of max elements to keep track of.

Since the aux heap has a fixed max size (5) I think that operations on that structure can be considered `O(1)`. In that case the complexity is `O(n)`.

Pseudo code:

```
foreach element in list:
    if aux_heap.size() < 5  
        aux_heap.add(element)
    else if element > aux_heap.top()
        aux_heap.remove_top()
        aux_head.add(element)
```

Comment: In the general case this is O(nlogk), although I agree it is superior is k = 5.

Comment: By Auxiliary list do you mean extra space ? Like an extra array ? Or is it something else?

Comment: @sTEAK: yes extra space. But of course I think it's necessary even with your solution, since you remove the elements from the original list and I guess put them somewhere else.

Comment: In general case it's O(nk), since insertion to list is O(k).

Comment: @Heisenbug is it better than my solution? is it being done in one traversal ? or is it also O(nk)

Comment: @sdcvvc it's O(n log k) if you use a heap.

Comment: sorry I was away. @cmh is right. better using an heap for O(nlogn). I'll fix the answer thanks.

Comment: Better than mine ( O(nlogk) vs O(nk) ) . Accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Using a [partial quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting) we can achieve O(n), this doesn't require any auxiliary space. Using a max heap, as in the other solution requires O(n log k) time.