# How to find the first m smallest integers in an array in O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

When the array has length of n and 1 <= m <= n^0.5

I think you can use a selection algorithm to find the mth smallest integer(there is a complicated one called BFPRT in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm that is O(n)) and then use that as a pivot to partition the array to get the first m smallest integers.

But, is there a way to do this using a data structure such as a min-heap? And how can I know if it's O(n)?

Comment: It seems to me that the answer is embedded in your question - according to Wikipedia, min-max heap can be built in O(n) time. And once you have that, it should be very simple to get the m smallest elements.

Comment: See pythons heapq nsmallest, http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577206/generate-top-k-values http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956593/optimal-algorithm-for-returning-top-k-values-from-an-array-of-length-n http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011350/top-5-elements-in-an-unsorted-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a min-heap in linear time. Then you just need to remove the minimum element `m` times with cost `log(n)` for each removal. That's `O(n) + m*O(log(n))` which is `O(n) + O(sqrt(n)*log(n))` which is `O(n)`.

**edit** I originally said `O(n) + O(sqrt(n)*log(n))` is `O(sqrt(n)*log(n))` which is wrong because `O(n)` is actually `o(sqrt(n)*log(n))` which implies it's not `O(sqrt(n)*log(n))`

Comment: He needs to at least check all the cells in the array once. So linear is the minimum

Comment: Yes because it was wrong. I'll add a note in the answer to reflect that

Answer (score 4):

Simply use radix sort to sort the array in O(n) time.

Comment: This is true for most practical purposes, but it's worth noting that radix sort depends on the length of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Build_Heap(A) method can create min_heap or max_heap from random array in O(n) time , if we creates min_heap then it takes O(1) time to get smallest element

so total time to get smallest element is O(n)+)(1)
                             that is       O(n)